# Help with venting an instant pot

Tags: kitchen

We have a primary range hood over the stove.

We have a different counter on which we use an instant pot frequently. It vents steam and odor. Are there general recommendations on how to vent this? Currently, it sits below a cabinet and vents onto the cabinet. The cabinets wear out over time with the steam.

I see many people seem to have it setup this way as instant pots become more common.

If a second hood cannot be placed, are there other things that can be done to improve the situation?

Answer (score 2):

What I do is this:

[image: Large mug sitting upside down covering both steam vents.]

Some steam still escapes, but most of it condenses inside the mug and trickles down into the unit's collection cup (don't forget to empty and clean it occasionally).

It works better if the mug has been kept in the freezer.
And a larger mug is better than a smaller one.

Also note that if you do this at the beginning, while heating the pot, make sure that the cup isn't sitting on the pop-up vent (otherwise it will never pop up and seal the container).

---

I've never tried it, but simply covering the vents with a wet dish towel might work too.

Comment: Dish towel works too, but some steam passes through.

Comment: Oh nice, never considered this, great idea. I assume there's no safety issue: if the steam (for some reason) is powerful enough, it'll probably just push over the mug. Thank you!